# Convert RGB image in Mat to BYTE * in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, mfc, mat

Sorry for putting it out here but `opencv` site is down or something i cannot access the topic there. I am reading a `RGB image` in `Mat` and than trying to convert in into `BYTE*` using the following function but it is not giving me the exact image but distorted part of some of the image. Please can anyone help me out here where i am mistaking it. Thank you.

```
BYTE *change_to_BYTE(Mat matrix_value)
{

    BYTE* v_char_new = new BYTE[matrix_value.rows * matrix_value.cols * 3]();


    vector<byte> v_char;
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix_value.rows; i++)
    {   
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix_value.cols; j++)
        {
            v_char_new[((i*matrix_value.cols+j) * 3)+0] = (*(uchar*)((matrix_value.data+ i*matrix_value.step + j + 0)));             
            v_char_new[((i*matrix_value.cols+j) * 3)+1] = (*(uchar*)((matrix_value.data+ i*matrix_value.step + j +1))); 
            v_char_new[((i*matrix_value.cols+j) * 3)+2] = (*(uchar*)((matrix_value.data+ i*matrix_value.step + j +2))); 
        }           
    }

    return v_char_new;
}
```

Comment: What does "distorted part of some of the image" mean? What kind of distored is it?

Comment: the result image is showing 1/3 of the input image. I got it working though will post answer after one day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking it out in different ways this was the one that worked for me.

```
  BYTE *Ctest_face_projectDlg::change_to_BYTE(Mat matrix_value)
    {

        BYTE* v_char_new = new BYTE[matrix_value.rows * matrix_value.cols * 3]();

        for(int i = 0; i < matrix_value.rows; i++)
        {
           for(int j = 0; j < matrix_value.cols; j++)
           {
               Vec3b bgrPixel = matrix_value.at<Vec3b>(i, j);
               v_char_new[((i*matrix_value.cols+j)*3)+0] = bgrPixel.val[0];
               v_char_new[((i*matrix_value.cols+j)*3)+1] = bgrPixel.val[1]; 
               v_char_new[((i*matrix_value.cols+j)*3)+2] = bgrPixel.val[2];
               // do something with BGR values...
           }
        }
    }
```